# Laravel сервер выдаёт ошибку 500 при одновременных запросов с клиента

Tags: laravel, axios

Ошибка появляется не часто но периодически при загрузке страницы текст ошибки точно не помню но там что-то в духе "acess denied to get user personal acess token" это не особо важно, ведь сервер попросту ломается от одновременных запросов по непонятной причине. Со стороны клиента то есть множество способов исправить то что запросы будут отправляться одновременно, но интересно вот что нормально ли то что сервер себя вообще так ведёт? Ведь даже если я исправлю одновременные запросы с клиента, пользователи при заходе на сайт всё так же будут отправлять запросы вместе, в таком случае оно всё так же будет ломаться или только если это делает один клиент?

Comment: Как сами думаете - нормально ли, что сервер "иногда" отдает 500ю ошибку и причем это иногда случается постоянно? Думаю, где то в коде у вас ошибка... надо дебажить